# Using Splunk MLTK functionality while in another Splunk app

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, splunk

I need to use a number of regression models on some index data. This index data is in an app called "XY". However, thus far, I have only been able to use the regression modelling on the Splunk MLTK app. Is it possible to call such  functionality in the Splunk MLTK app while inside another app which has the data you wish to model on? Otherwise, what alternatives can I do in this situation?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) issue - make sure you have proper permissions to data (indices, KOs, apps, etc), and that the *apps* have proper permissions

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "RBAC issue"?

Comment: @PatrickO'Rourke - i added a link to wikipedia's page on RBAC. In short, permissions